# IntelliJ IDE 2017.3.2 Maven Project packagingexcludes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a maven project that is going out to tomcat using a **exploded war** build in development.  I have the following entry in my pom to exclude certain files for any non development environments:

```
  <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>web</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webXml>web/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/classes/application.properties,
                        WEB-INF/classes/proxool.xml,
                        WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties,
                        WEB-INF/classes/wetemplates/**
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

The packaging excludes are being used by intellij and excluded from my local development build and breaking it.  I have been having to comment this block out in development for the environment to function correctly.  How can I resolve this so that these are not excluded in my development environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maven profiles to configure the build in such way that the Intellij build will use one given profile and the Maven/external build will use another profile.

Take a look at here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Thanks!  I struggled for a minute trying to figure out how to tell Intellij to use the new profile.  This is done in the maven projects dialog and a profiles node appears after specifying it in the pom.  Simply check the profile that you want intellij to use for the build.